# VS Code not resolving module path aliases in an Angular 17 monorepo

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, monorepo

I have an `Angular 17` monorepo workspace with two applications that share code from one library project `my-lib` in the same workspace. Although the workspace builds and the apps run, I see **errors in VS Code** similar to

```
Cannot use namespace '<user-defined type name>' as a type. ts(2709)
```

My workspace directory structure looks like this:

```
my-workspace
  .vscode/settings.json
  angular.json
  tsconfig.json
  package.json
  ...
  projects
    app1
      tsconfig.app.json
      src
        app
        environments
      ...
    app2
      tsconfig.app.json
      src
        app
        environments
      ...
    my-lib
      tsconfig.lib.json
      src
        lib
      ...
```

The app-level `tsconfig.app.json` files **extend** the top-level `tsconfig.json` and define app-specific path aliases. For example, the `tsconfig.app.json` in `app1` would look like this:

```json
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["node"],
    "paths": {
      "@app1/*": ["projects/app1/src/app/*"],
      "@app1-env/*": ["projects/app1/src/environments/*"],
...
```

The top-level `tsconfig.json` defines a `baseUrl`, but does not include any path aliases.

##### tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    ...
  },
```

##### angular.json

```json
    "app1": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss",
          "changeDetection": "OnPush"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "projects/app1",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/app1/src",
      "prefix": "pta",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/app1",
            "index": "projects/app1/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/app1/src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": ["zone.js"],
            "tsConfig": "projects/app1/tsconfig.app.json",
...
```

My `.vscode/settings.json` includes the following:
`"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative"`

I tried changing that to `relative`, but that did not help.

I have actually managed to get rid of the errors in `VS Code` by **duplicating the definitions** of the app-specific path aliases (`@app1`, `@app1-env`, `@app2`, `@app2-env`) in the top-level `tsconfig.json`.

Is there a better/correct solution to this issue than having the path alias definitions duplicated?